# Thermodynamic Bath

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, differential-equations

My textbook states that a bath is so large, its equilibrium state remains constant even though it can exchange different quantities (energy, volume, particles) with the system. But how would its equilibrium state (S, E, V, N, P, T, µ) stays constant even though extensive quantities are being exchanged between the system and the bath? if we couple a system (B) to a system (A) of interest, how do we mathematically express the conditions for system (B) to be considered a heat, particle, or volume bath?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_reservoir

Comment: So I have to assume that the system's extensive parameters (S, E, V, N) are all infinite to rigorously sustain constant (T, P, µ).

Comment: what do you mean by "rigorously"?

Comment: My question is how are we assuming constant (T, P, µ) while (S, E, V, N) of the bath are changing as the bath interacts with the system? aren't all (S, E, V, N, P, T, µ) interrelated for the bath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power of thermodynamics comes at the cost of certain assumptions and idealization. One is that the macroscale involves so many particles, moving randomly, that trillions and trillions of collisions of gas molecules against a surface can be averaged over a familiar time interval to produce a nominally uniform pressure. A system with exponential powers of 10, 20, or 30 is summarized by a single number! Now, perhaps this pressure can be known even in theory only to a relative precision of one billionth—no matter; this is sufficient for calculations. Our measurement precision in practice probably isn't this good.

A related case holds for the fiction of the perfect heat reservoir (or, for that matter, the idealization of reversibility). It is but a practical matter to construct a heat reservoir of, say, a vast amount of stirred fluid, such that nearly any amount of heat can be absorbed or dispensed without changing the bulk temperature by any notable amount. Since this arrangement is conceivable, we naturally take advantage of it for modeling convenience. Yes, cooling an actual large heat reservoir might decrease its temperature by a millionth of a kelvin. We ignore this and other negligible changes for convenience. Thermodynamics is about tendencies that are notable and that persist over any scale.

Comment: So am I right to assume that the bath is so large that its entropy S(E,V,N) can be considered linear in E, V, and N so that all its partial derivatives are constant?

Comment: Yes, and I like the way you express it: the bath is so large that changes in the extensive parameters are negligible, so changes in the intensive parameters—being the partial derivatives—are negligible as well.